# How to put multiple items on the same row in ScrollView (ReactNative)

Tags: list, react-native, scrollview

I am trying to implement the following picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNPBJ.jpg)

I have an array of strings that I should go through and display each in a ScrollView.
(I also used FlatList and used the number of columns but I don't know how big the words are)

It would be helpful if someone could tell me how is it done.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I write a code for you. hope will helpful for you

```
<View style={styles.viewList}>
                {array.map((val,key)=>{
                    return(
                        <View key={key} style={[styles.cap,styles.shadow]}>
                            <Text>{val}</Text>
                            </View>
                    )
                })}
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   viewList:{
   flexDirection:"row",
   flexWrap:"wrap",
   },
   cap:{
   backgroundColor:"#fff",
   alignItems:"center",
   justifyContent:"center",
   paddingVertical:10,
   paddingHorizontal:15,
   margin:5,
   borderRadius:20
   },
   shadow:{
   shadowColor: "#000",
   shadowOffset: {
         width: 0,
         height: 2,
   },
   shadowOpacity: 0.25,
  shadowRadius: 3.84,

  elevation: 5,
  }
})
```